# yarn is using 100% resources when running a hive job

Tags: hadoop, memory, hive, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I'm running a hive tez job. the job is to load the data from one table which is of text file format to another table with orc format.

I'm using

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ORDERREQUEST_ORC 
PARTITION(DATE)
SELECT 
COLUMN1, 
COLUMN2, 
COLUMN3,
DATE
FROM ORDERREQUEST_TXT;
```

When I'm monitoring the job through ambari web console I saw that YARN memory utilized is 100%.

can you please advice how to maintain Healthy Yarn memory.

the load average on all the three datanodes;

```
 1. top - 17:37:24 up 50 days, 3:47, 4 users, load average: 15.73, 16.43, 13.52 
 2. top - 17:38:25 up 50 days, 3:48, 2 users, load average: 16.14, 15.19, 12.50 
 3. top - 17:39:26 up 50 days, 3:49, 1 user, load average: 11.89, 12.54, 10.49
```

These are the yarn configurations

```
 yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=5120 
 yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=46080 
 yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=46080
```

FYI:- My cluster config

```
 Nodes = 4 (1 Master, 3 DN ) 
 memory = 64 GB on each node 
 Processors = 6 on each node 
 1 TB on each node (5 Disk * 200 GB)
```

How to reduce the yarn utilization memory?

Comment: 5 GB per container *minimum*?? But anyway, what are the actual `hive.tez.container.size` (defaulting to `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`) and `tez.am.resource.memory.mb ` (defaulting to `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb`)?

Answer (score 5):

you are getting the error because the cluster hasn't been configured to allocate max yarn memory per user.

Please set the below properties in Yarn configurations to allocate 33% of max yarn memory per job, which can be altered based on your requirement.

Change from:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
```

To:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=0.33
```

If you need further info on this, please refer following link
https://analyticsanvil.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/managing-yarn-memory-with-multiple-hive-users/

Comment: @Foxan Ng - Can we use the set Parameter while submitting this job ? Will it take effect ?

Comment: Also , one more questions, is that parameter only for default queue, or setting that parameter puts all queue in the .33 % usage ?